# Update assets name by giving new name on each build

Tags: javascript, angular, build, internationalization

I have en-US.json file on my project, when I am updating text, it is not appearing on client's view, because browser caching this file, so I am came out with solution like giving unique name on each build, example "en-US.json?version=122312", so it updates last changes on client's view

**i18n.module.ts**

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    httpClient,
    EApplicationStrings.LANGUAGE_FILES_PATH,
    EApplicationStrings.LANGUAGE_FILES_EXTENSION + `?version=${VERSION}`,
  );
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: @Random how to implement it

Comment: You could add a `version` property to your [environment configuration](https://angular.io/guide/build). Importing the `package.json` would work as well though it would include the whole package.json in the bundle, which I'd not recommend.